# Definite integral of strictly increasing postive function

Tags: real-analysis

Let f be a strictly increasing, continuous function on [0,1]. Then the claim is that the integral $\int_0^1 \frac{f(x)}{f(x) + f(1-x)} = \frac{1}{2}$. The hint to use the substitution $y = 1 - x$ is given, but left me stumped. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When substituted, you should get something... something good will happen when you add the substituted integral and original integral!

Comment: Thank you for the hint, though sadly a complete solution has already been given. I'll keep the trick in mind!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. By the change of variable $x \to 1-x$ one gets
$$
I=\int_0^1 \frac{f(x)}{f(x) + f(1-x)}dx=\int_0^1 \frac{f(1-x)}{f(1-x) + f(x)}dx
$$ then
$$
2I=I+I=\int_0^1 \frac{f(x)+f(1-x)}{f(x) + f(1-x)}dx=\int_0^1 1\:dx=1.
$$

Comment: I can't believe I missed that; thank you very much!

Comment: @JanDeMeyer You are welcome!